# excel formula to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, function, formula

This is the excel formula that I have

```
fx = ROUNDUP(C17/((1-(1/(1+(C19/12))^(C18*12)))/(C19/12)),0)
```

[image: excel formula]

This is the result should be : 
[image: the result]

This is the javascript function that I wrote:

```
function refreshRenoLoanCalculator() {

    var amt = parseInt($('.calc-renoloan .principal-amount').val().replace(/,/g, ''), 10)
    console.log(amt); //10 000
    var rate = $('.calc-renoloan .loan-rate').val();
    console.log(rate); //0.0444
    var tenure = $('.calc-renoloan .loan-tenure').val();
    console.log(tenure); // 5

    var a = rate / 100. / 12.;
    console.log(a); 
    var b = 1. + a;
    b = Math.pow(b, (tenure * 12)) - 1.;
    console.log(b); 
    var FC = a / b + a;
    FC = FC.toFixed(10);
    console.log(FC);
    var RP = amt * FC;
    console.log(RP);




    toolsSetCalculatedValue('.calc-renoloan .calc-result-installment', Math.ceil(RP).toLocaleString().split('.')[0])
    $('.calc-renoloan .results-container').slideDown();

}
```

At the moment the result that I'm getting from the excel formula and the javascript function is not the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also add the Excel formula in plain text, for copying / formatting purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS the equivalent calculation would be this:

```js
var C17 = 10000;
var C18 = 5;
var C19 = 4.44;

var interest = C19 / 1200;
var foo = Math.ceil(C17 * interest / (1 - (Math.pow(1/(1 + interest), C18 * 12))));

console.log(foo);
```

The main difference is the multiplication of the interest rate (`* 1200` as opposed to `* 12`) as Excel stores percentage values as floating points between `0` and `1`.

If you'd prefer to calculate in the same manner as Excel, then you need to convert the input rate to this:

```js
var C17 = 10000;
var C18 = 5;
var C19 = 0.0444; // Note the difference here

var interest = C19 / 12; // and here
var foo = Math.ceil(C17 * interest / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + interest), C18 * 12))));

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Thank you. this works perfectly. Getting the same result as the excel.